# Cleaning up tags coming from closed questions

Tags: discussion

[This closed question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-is-the-most-common-variant-of-poker) is the only source of the 2 tags `variants` and `worldwide`.  I don't think those tags belong on the site.  A question has to have at least 1 tag, but it seems a shame to let these 2 inappropriate tags live solely for a question that was closed.

If I recall, tags like `off-topic` or `subjective` are frowned upon.  Can we edit the question to remove those 2 tags, while putting something more appropriate in their place?

If you think the tags do belong, why?  What are examples of questions where they would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are removed from the database automatically about a day after they are no longer in use. The solution is to retag the question appropriately so it does not hold on to ill-advised tags. If the community does its job, the question should eventually be deleted. That will take care of the problem, too.

And, no, adding place-holder tags like [off-topic] would not be appropriate. Those are meta tags and they are discouraged: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).